# olsrr error in model.frame.default, variable lengths differ

Tags: r, linear-regression

I run this code in the `olsrr` package:

```
model <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)
```

where the df is the dataframe of interest. I got the following error.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'var1')
```

Comment: Hi there, what data frame are you using.

Comment: Thanks. have tried the using the "tbl_df", "tbl" and the "data.frame" and still getting the same error.

Comment: And even tried measuring the lengths of the individual variables and they are the same lengths. I don't know what to do please help.

Comment: Have you checked all your variables for NAs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints from the other posts.
This issue is resolved by the following steps;

df1 <- dplyr::select(df,A1:A7)

df2 <- df1[complete.cases(df1), ]

Running these two removes the error.
The rest follows from there.